# Update nested setState Object - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```
this.state = {
    qs: {catName:'',subCatName:''}
}
```

I have the above nested state object. In order to setState, I used the below code in componentDidUpdate.

```
var newQs = {...this.state.qs}
newQs.catName = 'name';
this.setState({qs: newQs});
```

But it does not working, still this.state.qs is empty not updated. I even tried the following one.

```
this.setState({...this.state, qs: {
    ...this.state.qs,
    catName: 'name'
}});
```

Still not works.

Comment: Actually, your last code should work. But, you don't need ...this.state here since React merges other parts of your state with your new qs.

Answer (score 3):

Use setState like this:

```
this.setState( prevState =>
    ( { qs: { ...prevState.qs, catName: 'name' } } )
)
```

You don't need here `...this.state` since React merges other parts of your state.

Also I edited my suggestion according to @kuby's comment. React now recommends using a function with prevState instead of directly setting the state. This is because state updates may be asynchronous. So, using a function is a better approach here. If we don't use a function that does not mean always there will be problems but there could be and being in the safe side is always a better approach.

Related doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: `this.setState(prevState => {
      return { qs: {...prevState.qs, catName: 'name'} }
    })`

Comment: I tried both solutions. It's not updating the state. @devserkan And Also checked without nested state(like this.state = {catName: ''}) for this also setState not working for me. FYI, I am importing react-redux in this component.

Comment: Can you show us your whole component or upload it somewhere else like codesandbox.io or stackblitz.com?

Comment: I uploaded my code here codesandbox.io/s/github/arsarvahventures/build src->components->containers -> catalog-container @devserkan

Comment: It seems working, I can see catName is changing from "" to "name".